# whats is the difference between EXE created by C++ and other languages (such as Visual Basic or C)

Tags: c++, vb.net

I have 2 questions here:

1. I know that EXE file created by C++ runs much faster than VB, but why? aren't they both turned into machine code after they are compiled?
2. If C++ is compiled into machine code, why is it OS dependent. For example why can't you run the complied output on Linux? If it has to do with libraries (like stdio.h) aren't they also converted into machine language?

Answer (score 5):

1. While C++ is indeed compiled to machine code, VB (and C#) is not. VB (and C# and other .NET languages) are compiled to what is called MSIL (microsoft intermediate language) which is machine code for a virtual ideal machine. Machine code for a virtual machine is generally called "bytecode". These instructions are compiled into actual machine code on the fly (JIT (just in time) compilation) by the CLR (common language runtime). The consequence of doing it this way is actually that a VB program can run on pretty much any machine without needing to be compiled more than once. It runs slower (slightly) because it needs to be JIT'd, however most performance issues have been resolved over the past decade or so and its no longer true that C# or VB is always slower than C++ (don't knock it 'till you try it on performance...for 90% of applications it will probably be the same). In some cases, C# can be faster because the JIT compiler does some interesting optimizations while the code is running which is not always possible with a compiled C++ program. To summarize:

   - C++, C and other languages like them are compiled directly to machine code. It must be compiled for each machine architecture that will be used.
   - C#, VB, Java, and other similar lanaguages are compiled to a "bytecode" which corresponds to the machine code for some ideal virtual machine. This code is translated by some sort of runtime into machine code for the particular machine when the program is actually run. Generally, the code only has to be compiled once in order to run on any machine (not always true in .NET, but true enough as long as you don't get fiddly with the settings)
2. It is OS dependent for several reasons. I'll list a few that I think are important:

   - The formats of the executables vary significantly between operating systems. An executable is just a file and has a specific format just like any other file. Also, an executable doesn't just contain your code. There is some initialization for setting up how the program looks in memory and things like that. For example, linux uses the ELF format. Windows uses something different (sorry...heavy linux user here). It may be the same machine code on Windows and Linux, but its the initialization and file format that matters.
   - This deserves its own bullet point, so in addition to the file formats being different, the sequence needed to start a program and the dirty details of implementation of the standard library will vary between operating systems. Things like threads and processes may be the same conceptually between operating systems, but their implementations can be very different. User permissions and how those work are extremely varied. Files and file systems are also quite different. You get the picture...
   - Shared libraries. If you use any part of the standard library (`<string>` for example) it is often loaded from a shared library (`.dll` in windows, `.so` in linux). The bit of code to actually load the library varies greatly between operating systems. Even the way that the functions are called can vary.
   - System calls. Without you realizing it, your code will almost always make a system call. Your code needs to be able to run in a scheduled environment as a process and it needs to be able to listen to signals from the operating system about that sort of stuff. Almost all operating systems have their very own way of implementing this.

Comment: But I thought machine code is run directly on CPU. Isn't machine code some CPU instructions? then why do you even need the OS here (i mean why is OS so important) if code can run directly on a CPU architecture it was compiled for.

Comment: The code is run directly on the CPU, but it isn't given every privilege possible. How bad would it be if any program could decide to change some hardware settings about the power usage of your computer or something else like that? The operating system gets every privilege possible and it is in charge of delegating those privileges to programs. So, your program gets run, but the operating system actually told the cpu what your program is allowed to do while it is running and the operating system can stop your program at any time.

Comment: Also, the OS takes care of stuff like writing to the hard drives or swapping out memory when needed (your program doesn't have privleges to do that...it asks the OS to do it through standard library calls such as `fopen`). If every program had to implement this, it would be the 60's all over again. Your programs would be big and complicated and you would have to know every inner working of the computer that you are executing on in order to write the simplest of programs.

Comment: So then is it possible to run a C++ compiled code without an operating system?feed it to CPU using a boot loader or something similar.

Comment: It is possible. That's how operating systems are written and how they work (Linux is mostly written in C...I believe windows is written in C or C++). In addition, things like the [arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/) are programmed in C++ (or C) and the program that you write executes directly on the processor with no intervening operating system. When you do that, however, you need to include everything: Telling the CPU how to start, telling the hard drives how to talk to you, telling the memory management unit how to swap stuff, etc.